# Using laptop as third monitor? Best way to set up (without thunderbolt)?

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, display

I currently  have a 27' iMac that uses a Samsung 16' monitor as a second display using Mini Display Port to VGA. I also have a 2011 Macbook Pro and was wondering if there was a way to set up this up as a third monitor to the iMac. The MDP is already in use, so what would be my options (if there are any) for connecting a laptop as another monitor? Also note that this monitor does not have thunderbolt, so thats out.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [AirDisplay](https://avatron.com/applications/air-display/). It supports turning you Mac, Windows, iOS or Android into an external screen.

There are several other apps like this such as [Screen Recycler](http://www.screenrecycler.com/ScreenRecycler.html), but AirDisplay is the one I currently use.

Any of these apps will likely work best on a wired ethernet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Screen Sharing option in the syst preferences -sharing would be a option, but obviously it will show the same screen.

Check the set up at this Apple article https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18696?locale=en_US